# Splitting string with regular expression to make it array without empty element

Tags: javascript, regex

Here, I have example  javascipt string:

```
example_string = "Answer 1| Answer 2| Answer 3|";
```

I am trying to get array like this using regular expression:

```
Array ["Answer 1", " Answer 2", " Answer 3"]
```

I have tried:

```
result = example_string.split('/[|]+/g');
```

and also with the following patterns

```
'/[|]+/g'
'/[|]+\b/g'
'/[|]+[^$]/g'
```

And I am still getting an array with empty element at the end of it:

```
 Array ["Answer 1", " Answer 2", " Answer 3", ""]
```

That cause me lot of trouble. Does anyone know where I am making mistake in my pattern or how to fix it?

Comment: why dont u just remove the last item in array? seeems prety simple...

Comment: Just use: `example_string.match(/[^|]+/g);`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does string.split with a regular expression that contains a capturing group return an array that ends with an empty string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38261359/why-does-string-split-with-a-regular-expression-that-contains-a-capturing-group)

Comment: No capture groups in this question. Not a duplicate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I always liked matching everything I always hated split but:

Regex for splitting: `(\|(?!$))` [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/iP8lV6)

Matching instead of splitting:

Regex: `(?:([\w\s]+)\|?)`

You can even use `[^\|]+` To match whatever you have to match BUT `|`

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fL9yG9)

Comment: You are right seems like match is much better then split, I eventually ended up using it instead. Your first regex for split worked fine but now last array element had "|" at the end of string. Still regex for match method works great at site you provided but my browser(Opera and FF) gave wrong result because each element had "|"  at the end of string. I've fixed that modyfing your regex to ([\w\s]+[^|]). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

There is no mistake. This is absolutely correct behavior (how would `split` know that this is not a CSV file with the last column having an empty value?). If you know your string always ends in `|`, you could remove the last one first manually. Or you could just take away the last element of the array if it is empty. However, I can't seem to find a possibility (in JavaScript) to tell the built-in `split` function to omit empty results.