# Split a string using regex expression in node js

Tags: node.js, regex

I wanted to split a string using regex expression.

The string is:

```js
var str = 'i want @masala tea@'
```

I want this string to be splitted into the array `['i want','masala tea']`

What I have tried so far was:

```js
var arr = str.split(/^@.*@$/);
```

but this did not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Splitting string with regular expression to make it array without empty element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13268770/splitting-string-with-regular-expression-to-make-it-array-without-empty-element). You could opt to use `str.match(/[^@]+/g)`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `spilt` function for this case. use `replace` funtion like this:

```
var str='i want @masala tea@';
console.log(str.replace(/@/gi, "")); //i want masala tea.
```

Thanks.

Comment: I believe OP asked for an array using, not a resulting string

Answer (score 1):

You can split your message on each '@' and then filter empty items. If you need to remove whitespace characters from each string use `.map(...)` function.

```js
'i want @masala tea@'.split('@').filter(e => e != ""); 
//["i want ", "masala tea"]
'i want @masala tea@'.split('@').map(e => e.trim()).filter(e => e != ""); 
//["i want", "masala tea"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can split string using regex expression.
Try this. i thing it will solve your problem.

```
let yourString = 'i want @masala tea@'; // your string 

// function that return exactly what you want
let outputArr = (string) => {
    return string.trim().match(/[^@]+/g).map(item => item.trim());
}

console.log(outputArr(yourString)); 
//(2) ["i want", "masala tea"]
```